# Is there a maximum video texture resolution in A-Frame?

Tags: three.js, webgl, aframe

I have a video-sphere and I want to map a high resolution (5100 x 2550px) video texture onto it.

```
<video
        id="my-video"
        preload="auto"
        src="./assets/video/video.mp4"
        crossorigin="anonymous"
        playsinline
        webkit-playsinline
      ></video>
```

...

```
 <a-videosphere play-on-click id="skyVideo" rotation="-30 0 0" src="#my-video" class="cantap">
    </a-videosphere>
```

When I load the high resolution video, the videosphere is black and I get the following error:
[WebGL Error 501](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nAj8.png)

When I downsize the video texture to 2560 x 1280, the videosphere shows the texture as expected with no errors.

***Is there a maximum texture resolution in AFrame or three.js that I am not aware of?***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The limit isn't established by A-Frame or Three.js, but by WebGL and your graphics card capabilities. Go to https://webglreport.com/ and look at the `Textures > Max Texture Size` field to see what the device you're using can handle. My laptop maxes out at 8192, my cellphone is lower, but my desktop goes higher. It varies depending on your GPU. My guess is that your machine maxes out at 4096.

[image]

You can get this value in Three.js with `WebGLRenderer.capabilities.maxTextureSize`, [as outlined in the docs](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer.capabilities) so you can read this value on different devices and adjust accordingly. Maybe you'd like to point to lower rez videos based on the limits.