# What is the meaning of WebGL: INVALID_VALUE: texImage2D: width or height out of range

Tags: javascript, three.js, frontend, webgl, post-processing

I want to use UnrealBloomPass in three.js postprocessing, but I get a black screen after adding effectComposer.addPass(unrealBloomPass), on the console I get the following

```
WebGL: INVALID_VALUE: texImage2D: width or height out of range

[.WebGL-00005F94023C4600] GL_INVALID_VALUE: Desired resource size is greater than max renderbuffer size.

[.WebGL-00005F94023C4600] GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION: Framebuffer is incomplete: Attachment has zero size.

[.WebGL-00005F94023C4600] GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION: Draw framebuffer is incomplete
```

I don't know what to do, please help.

I have done a bit of research, someone said I should lower the size of the image I used to generate the texture, I did it but to no avail. Please I need help. Thanks

I have already done all the import{...} needed.

Comment: `width or height out of range`  What width and height are you sending.   From what I can remember width & heights are usually meant to be a power of 2,  eg.   2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024,2048,4096 etc..

Comment: Thank you so much. The width of the image is 3942px and the height is 2246px

Comment: Does  4096 by 2048 work ok?

Comment: ok, let me try, I will inform you of the results

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work, the same errors are generated.

Comment: See the answer in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60517986/2608515 Texture limits vary depending on your graphics card.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a maximum video texture resolution in A-Frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60517986/is-there-a-maximum-video-texture-resolution-in-a-frame)

Comment: Thanks, I now get it

Comment: Thanks for your help, The problem was actually from webpack. I did it wrongly, but I have corrected it, and it is working. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Believe it or not, you need to add

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

to your index.html.

Worked for me ([via](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/22873)).